# Python: what are the nearest Linux and OS X [edit: macOS] equivalents of winsound.Beep?

Tags: python, linux, macos, audio

If one wishes to beep the speaker on Windows, Python 2 apparently provides a useful function: `winsound.Beep()`. The neat thing about this function is that it takes arguments specifying the exact frequency and duration of the beep. This is exactly what I want to do, except that I don't use Windows. So...

What are the nearest equivalents of `winsound.Beep()` for `Linux` and `OS X` [edit: `macOS`], bringing in as few dependencies as possible?

Please note that I want to be able to beep the speaker directly, not to play a sound file. Also, I need to be able to control the frequency and duration of the beep, so `curses.beep()` and `print '\a'` won't do. Lastly, I am aware that `PyGame` provides extensive sound capabilities, but given that I don't require any of PyGame's other functionality, that would seem like using a sledgehammer to crack a nut (and anyway, I'm trying to do away with dependencies as far as possible).

[Edited on 9 Feb 2023 to reflect the fact that OS X was renamed macOS a few years after this question was asked]

Comment: isnt there a character you can send to the terminal? (0x07) ?

Comment: @JoranBeasley: The last paragraph explains why that won't suffice.

Comment: ahh reading comprehension for the win ;P

Comment: "for the win" shouldn't it be "for the linux/mac"?

Comment: @BenJones When I asked this question, the native operating system of the Apple Mac was called OSX -- it was renamed a few years later

Answer (score 14):

winsound is only for windows and I could not find any cross platform way to do this, other than print "/a". However, you cannot set the frequency and duration with this.

However, you can try the os.system command to do the same with the system command [beep](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/utils/beep.html). Here is a snippet, which defines the function playsound in a platform independent way

```
try:
    import winsound
except ImportError:
    import os
    def playsound(frequency,duration):
        #apt-get install beep
        os.system('beep -f %s -l %s' % (frequency,duration))
else:
    def playsound(frequency,duration):
        winsound.Beep(frequency,duration)
```

For more info, look at [this blog](http://www.answermysearches.com/how-to-make-a-beep-sound-in-linux-and-a-fun-program-that-uses-it/295/)

EDIT: You will need to install the beep package on linux to run the beep command. You can install by giving the command

```
sudo apt-get install beep
```

Comment: Thanks, Himanshu. I'm voting this up but, because it introduces a dependency, I haven't accepted it as my answer. However, I realise that it may be impossible to do what I'm trying to do without dependencies. 'Beep' is at least a lesser dependency than PyGame!

Comment: On MacOS you can install sox via ports (sudo port install sox). Sox contain the play command. Here an example how to use it from python: os.system('play --no-show-progress --null --channels 1 synth %f sine %s' % ( duration/1000.0, frequency))

Answer (score 11):

I found a potential solution here:
http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/25217-beeping-under-linux

It involves writing directly to /dev/audio. Not sure how portable it is or if it even works at all - i'm not on a linux machine atm.

```
def beep(frequency, amplitude, duration):
    sample = 8000
    half_period = int(sample/frequency/2)
    beep = chr(amplitude)*half_period+chr(0)*half_period
    beep *= int(duration*frequency)
    audio = file('/dev/audio', 'wb')
    audio.write(beep)
    audio.close()
```

Comment: Thanks, Shawabawa. I'm voting this up, but because it can't work on OSX (which doesn't have `/dev/audio`), I haven't accepted it as 'the answer'. Maybe there is no perfect answer, but I'm still holding out!

Comment: I get a permission error too. Not sure how to fix it. The "folder" `/dev/audio` seems not to be a literal folder so not straightforward to change the relevant permissions.

Comment: For python3 user, 'file' should be replaced with 'open' at 6th line.

Answer (score 5):

### This works on mac:

```
import numpy as np
import simpleaudio as sa

def sound(x,z):
 frequency = x # Our played note will be 440 Hz
 fs = 44100  # 44100 samples per second
 seconds = z  # Note duration of 3 seconds

 # Generate array with seconds*sample_rate steps, ranging between 0 and seconds
 t = np.linspace(0, seconds, seconds * fs, False)

 # Generate a 440 Hz sine wave
 note = np.sin(frequency * t * 2 * np.pi)

 # Ensure that highest value is in 16-bit range
 audio = note * (2**15 - 1) / np.max(np.abs(note))
 # Convert to 16-bit data
 audio = audio.astype(np.int16)

 # Start playback
 play_obj = sa.play_buffer(audio, 1, 2, fs)

 # Wait for playback to finish before exiting
 play_obj.wait_done()

sound(300,2)

sound(200,1)
```

Comment: Why such 440 Hz references in comments ? seems like frequency is the x parameter, not some fixed value.

Comment: Actually this looks pretty cross-platform

Answer (score 2):

The most light-weight cross-platform layer I can see is "PortAudio".  This is used by R for instance in their package to wrap platform-specific driver calls into simple play/record of digitized waveforms as an array.
The good folk at M.I.T. produce a Python binding for this, but you will need to include the compiled .dll/.so for this to work. http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/

( libao is similar by Xiph the makers of Ogg/Vorbis , a wrapper pyao exists but this seems less widely used )

SoX is an excellent set of cross-platform tools with much more functionality for format conversion and reading files etc..

Using ctypes to make calls from Python to a driver is feasible but very messy, even the simplest legacy WinMM.

Answer (score 0):

I've found 3 methods for Linux:

- new method using the Linux evdev API, works with any user in the `input` group ([example source code](https://gist.github.com/zed/9af4ebc7136348721677a35d7fd8cc84))
- old method using `fcntl` and `/dev/console` (requires root priviledges) ([example source code](https://gist.github.com/shimarin/2358720))
- invoke the `beep` command directly with `subprocess` or `os.system` (slower and must be installed in the system).

See also [my tone() function here with all the alternatives](http://eadmaster.altervista.org/pub/prj/cliapps/rtttl2beep.py).