# Making a synthesized sound at arbitrary pitch in python

Tags: python, audio, synthesizer

I'm finding it strangely hard to find a synthesizer module for python that allows the program to play a note at an arbitrary pitch. Preferably the note should be more than just a pure sinewave and should include at least a few harmonics - it should be more than just a beep.

The idea is to be able to write something like

```
the_module.play(frequency, loudness, duration)
```

or

```
my_synth = the_module.newsynth()
my_synth.play(frequency, loudness, duration)
```

where frequency is specified in Hz, and have a synthesized tone play from the user's speakers. There's JavaScript modules for doing this, such as [Tone.js](https://tonejs.github.io/), but does anyone know of an approach using Python?

Answer (score 1):

If on windows, you can use the builtin [`winsound.Beep`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/winsound.html#winsound.Beep).

If on Linux, you need to write directly to `/dev/audio`, like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12354772/5052365):

```py
def beep(frequency, amplitude, duration):
    sample = 8000
    half_period = int(sample/frequency/2)
    beep = chr(amplitude)*half_period+chr(0)*half_period
    beep *= int(duration*frequency)
    audio = file('/dev/audio', 'wb')
    audio.write(beep)
    audio.close()
```

Comment: This looks interesting, but can you explain what the Linux code is doing a bit more? Why is chr() being called, for example?

Comment: By the way, I couldn't get this to work, due to file permission issues.